# Where does LineageOs store stock browser bookmarks?

Tags: backup, lineageos, stock-browser, bookmarks

How could I export or backup my bookmarks in the LineageOS 14.1 default browser?

- Several apps failed to retrieve bookmarks
- The name of the browser doesn't appear anywhere in the browser itself
- `find /data/data | grep browser` through adb doesn't give anything interesting
- `find /data/fata | grep "db$"` does neither
- Google doesn't help

It's a shame there isn't an "Export" option in the settings

Answer (score 0):

The stock browser is named Jelly and its bookmarks are stored in:
`/data/data/org.lineageos.jelly/databases/FavoriteDatabase`

The bookmarks can then be exported to CSV with SQLite parsers like [this one](https://sqliteonline.com/).